# Symfony messaging queue with job progress and planned tasks? (DtcQueueBundle)

Tags: symfony, message-queue

I am currently using [DtcQueueBundle by mmucklo](https://github.com/mmucklo/DtcQueueBundle) as messenger queue for my symfony project. I was wondering why it does not support any kind of progress. Even other bundles I was looking at did not support anything like that, which brings me to the following question:

Why is there no progress / status update while a specific jobs is being processed?
If there isn't any major reason for not doing anything like that, what would be the best way to update the job progress during the run?
*For instance: I trigger a job to pull products from an endpoint and want to show the progress in frontend if anybody opens the product page to see how many products are already processed.*

Besides that I recognized, that none of the existing bundles provide something like planned tasks? I would like to use the queue instead of using cron.

Comment: Queue and Crons are two different things, You can only use a Queue, when the time of execution is not critical or important. 
What do you mean with progress? Progress of the execution of ONE task? or progress of general execution like percentage of tasks executed from total number of tasks?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I was talking about the progress of one job which is being triggered from the frontend. I updated my question with an example.

Comment: Does the queue server support this feature "progress of a task"?

Comment: I am not using a queue server, because there is no need yet. Using the provided php command to run the queue. I thought of using some methods similar to the [Symfony Progress Bar](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/helpers/progressbar.html), to update a field in queue table, but it seems like I am the only one wanting to do that, so it "feels wrong" to do it.

Another idea would be to process every product as single job, so I could count all "product" jobs and compare it with all product jobs, that have been processed already